# Truncate y_true in custom Keras loss (TF backend)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to eliminate the effect that the necessity of padding has on my sequences in terms of learning so I'm trying to remove the trailing zeroes that sequences may have before calculating the MSE. Stopping the gradient that way seems better to me than trying to feed sequences of different length when it comes to stability.

However, my code throws different errors for different approaches. For this approach, which seemed the most promising for me, it's `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'` thrown from `K.update_sub(i,1)`

```
def truncated_MSE(y_true, y_pred):
    i = K.int_shape(y_true)[0]
    i = K.update_sub(i,1)
    while y_true[i][0] == 0 and y_pred[i][1] == 0:
        i = K.update_sub(i,1)
    y_true = y_true[:i]
    y_pred = y_pred[:i]

    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

PS: If that's bad python coding style, I'm happy to learn!

Comment: Have you thought of using `Masking` layers or use `mask_zero=True` in Embedding layers?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from applying Keras backend functions on regular integers instead of Tensor objects.

```
i = K.int_shape(y_true)[0]
```

This line produces an int, and can therefore not be used in a K.update_sub call. You can, however, just use normal python integer calculations on it.